# Two Activities requiring two separate databases

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I need to have two SQLite Databases. One to store usernames and passwords for a login Activity, and the other to store financial transactions for my app, in a different screen. What is the right approach of doing this? I've thought that I'll extend and use the SQLiteOpenHelper class (writing the code for query, insertion, etc. only once), and in the respective Activities, create instances of this class, and use them. Will I get two separate databases? I'm not sure what the right approach is.

Comment: Why not one database? Two tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the docs, you can define different named databases, sure.

```
SQLiteOpenHelper (Context context, 
                String name, 
                SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, 
                int version)

Parameters

- name  String: of the database file, or null for an in-memory database
```

Or you can have the same name and different `CREATE TABLE` queries, and the data is still separated.

Answer (score 2):

Use one database and just store the information in different tables.